PyQt6 app not responding while running the simulation in Python
I developed a desktop app in PyQt6. When I run, the simulation runs in background (I can see it in the terminal), it gives an output after a while. The simulation uses heavy computational resource like video analysis and object detection.
However, the UI does not response while running the simulation. It gets normal after completing the simulation.
Any recommendation how to solve it.

Qt, like almost any UI toolkit, is based on an event loop. That loop is also responsible to update ("redraw") the UI. If the process is occupied by something else, like an heavy demanding computation, this will delay any repaint. Do some research on the matter, as there are literally thousands of related resources about such issues. Be aware that many results will be about multithreading, but if your processing is CPU-bound (heavy computation), multithreading will be almost useless and you should consider multiprocessing instead. As above, do some proper research on the matter.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
